# Code duplication and SRT according to Robert C. Martin

Tags: code-duplication, single-responsibility-principle, clean-architecture

I'm reading Robert C. Martin's Clean Architecture book. In the example for the Single Responsibility Principle he demonstrates an interface for an Employee with three public methods: `calculatePay`, `reportHours` and `saveEmployee`:

```
class Employee {
public:
  float calculatePay();
  float reportHours();
  void saveEmployee();

private:
  float calculateRegularHours();
}
```

He argues that these three methods should not be contained in the same class, because they serve different actors: Chief Financial Officer, Chief Operating Officer and Chief Technical Officer. He then describes the consequences: If the CFO decides to change the method how regular working hours are calculated it might happen that accidentially the programmer also changes the calculation algorithm for the COO, because they rely on the same method calculateRegularHours.

My question is: How does adhering to the SRP help us out here? Even if we implemented `calculatePay` and `reportHours` in two different classes, they would still depend on the same method `calculateRegularHours`, so either we implement this method twice (which would be code duplication) or we have to accept the risk that changes to it will affect both actors.

Which point did I not see? How would you deal with this particular situation?

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: The point is that `calculateRegularHours` is *"accidental duplication"* (touched on here and in other parts of the book) in this case - it's **currently** the same, but has different reasons to change in each of the contexts it's used in.

Comment: So the method calculateRegularHours is used in two contexts and you know that they are implemented the same in both contexts, but you cannot guarantee that they will always be the same. So would you then duplicate this method just to reduce the risk that this function needs to be changed for just one of the two clients?

Answer (score 1):

> either we implement this method twice (which would be code duplication)

It looks like code duplication, but it's not. The fact that the implementation for `calculateRegularHours` that `calculatePay` and `reportHours` uses is the same, is just an accident.

Since `calculatePay` and `reportHours` serve different actors, they will change for different reasons at different times. So it's likely that one of these actors will request a change that the other actor don't want. So when it comes to this request, what would you do? I guess you would separate the `calculateRegularHours` logic into 2 implementations. One for the `calculatePay` and one for `reportHours`. But it's also likely that you forget it and you will break the system in a place that has nothing to do with the change you wanted to make. That make a system fragile.

Robert C. Martin explains it in [this video](https://youtu.be/Gt0M_OHKhQE?t=2366) (39:26 - 43:00).

I guess a better example of SRP violation is putting methods that serve the UI in the business object or even putting SQL in the view.

No matter what you do you should have tests, because the tests can show you that you broke the system in a complete other area. And if this happens you should re-think the design and remember the SRP.